# SonicWall QOS for VOIP

Tags: voip, sonicwall, qos

I has a Sonicwall NSA 220, I want to enable QOS on the network. But I want any device to be included so any VOIP call gets priority. I've seen guides on setting up QOS or bandwidth management but for these you specify the devices. If I was to do that I would be selecting all devices so defeats the object.

Currently we have issues with skype, go to meeting anything really via both wifi and physically LAN with 1Gb switches.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why you dont follow sonicwall guide to implement this ? That will QOS traffic gooing out, but for the switch you can enable QOS too, just follow your switch manual. Usually you will find common ground in both guide, as the goal is the same, prioritize VOIP.

Comment: QOS guides I found were all bandwidth management based on device ip. This is no use as its not just VOIP phones I want to prioritise but also computers handling VOIP. Any device on my network maybe handling VOIP. So this doesnt work for my requirement.

Comment: oh ok, I now understand, as usually I would use another VLAN for such traffic.

Comment: Yeah I would too but its common place now for users wanting to skype call from their laptops or desktops.